# How would you insert a Figure element in a contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, text-editor

I'm wondering how to implement a command to insert  `<figure>` elements in a contenteditable element. `Document.execCommand()` provides an `insertImage` command but nothing like I'm looking for.

Here is the snippet of code I'd like to insert:

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://example.org/image.jpg" alt="some text" />
    <figcaption>Here is a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom command and add your figure with src and caption.

See https://jsfiddle.net/2qjcLosq/

```
execCommand('insertfigure' ,'you_src','your_caption');
```